# Error en conexión al host

Tags: php, phpmailer

Recibo el siguiente de error en la conexión al host de PHPMailer:

> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 
>   SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Error.

Éste es mi código:

```
<?php 
require ('../../class/class.phpmailer.php');
require '../../class/class.smtp.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->Username   = 'test@gmail.com'; 
    $mail->Password   = '**********';
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; 
    $mail->Mailer = "smtp"; 

    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                
    $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

    $mail->setFrom('test@gmail.com', 'Test');
    $mail->addAddress('testok@gmail.com', 'Mensaje de Prueba');
    $mail->Subject  = 'Mensaje';
    $mail->Body = 'Cuerpo';
    $test =$mail->Send();
    if($test) {
      echo 'Enviado.';
      echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Error.';
    }

?>
```

¿Por qué recibo ese error y qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Comment: Desactiva el protector de correo que algunos antivirus usan Y mira si estas usando un correcto host

Comment: Hola Hernan. Por favor, lee [ask] e intenta dar mucha mas informacion de qué intentas y que sucede. Un saludo

Comment: Prueba cambiando el Port a 587 y SMTPSecure a tls.